# Access Exchange server 2010 Code using VB.NET code

Tags: c#, vb.net, exchange-server, exchange-server-2010

I have to create a console application. In this application I have to create the contact detail of different user. If my passed contact detail is already present than I don't have to  create that contact otherwise I have to create and save that contact in master account as well as the corresponding user account. Can any one have the idea what is the best and optimize way to do so. I believe I have to do some delegation and persuasion logic but I am not sure about it.

Comment: Any one have an idea about the solution?

Comment: @Bridge any idea about the solution..